# Display items from database in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm trying to display some items on webpage from a database. I have a function that loops through the data stored in the database. Currently it displays the last item that appears within the database rather than the first or anything else. I have tried ordering the items by the id but it gives the same result. I have also tried to display individual items of the array but it just displays the first character of the last item within the database.

### display items function:

```
<?php
    function get_product_details()
    {
        global $db;
        $ret = array();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Products";
        $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        while($ar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            $ret[] = $ar;
        }
        return $ret;
    }
?>
```

### Area for displaying items:

```
<article class = "main_area2">
            <h1 class = "food_h1">Menu</h1><br>
            <section class = "menu_section">
                <?php 
                    $products = get_product_details(); 

                    foreach($products as $ap)
                    {
                        $name = $ap['pro_name'];
                        $description = $ap['descr'];
                        $price = $ap['rrp'];
                    }
                ?>
                <div class = "section_4">
                    <h1 class = "food_h2"><?php echo $name; ?></h2>
                    <br><img src = "img/products/hassellback_pot.jpg" class = "img_dis">
                    <br><h1 class = "food_h2"><?php echo $description; ?></h1>
                    <br><h1 class = "food_h2">£ <?php echo $price; ?></h1>
                    <button class = "basket_btn" type = "button"> Buy </button>
                </div>
```

This is the current display and as you can see the first and last are exactly the same (the second to eighth are currently hard-coded).

[image: Display page]

P.S. Don't worry about closing the section & article with the close tags because it's already done.

Comment: Select query in your function and return array, then with foreach loop display data from function in this case array.

Comment: @Mario How do you mean? Provide example please.

Comment: Your `foreach` loop doesn't do anything except repeatedly over-write variables.  So after that loop those variables will *always* have the last values from the loop, guaranteed.  Should the *use* of those variables also be *inside* the loop?

Comment: @David Sorry, I'm a little confused - I'm quite unfamiliar with PHP so I'm not sure about what I'm doing so I need some examples.

Comment: Convert `mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)` to `$ret = mysqli_fetch_array($res);` to get a list of all items you dont need while loop in a fuction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looping over the array, but you're not *doing anything* with the values:

```
foreach($products as $ap)
{
    $name = $ap['pro_name'];
    $description = $ap['descr'];
    $price = $ap['rrp'];
}
```

Then *after* the loop, when the values are the last of the array, you finally use them *once*:

```
<div class = "section_4">
    <h1 class = "food_h2"><?php echo $name; ?></h2>
    <br><img src = "img/products/hassellback_pot.jpg" class = "img_dis">
    <br><h1 class = "food_h2"><?php echo $description; ?></h1>
    <br><h1 class = "food_h2">£ <?php echo $price; ?></h1>
    <button class = "basket_btn" type = "button"> Buy </button>
</div>
```

Instead, use the values in the loop so you can use *each* of them:

```
foreach($products as $ap)
{
    $name = $ap['pro_name'];
    $description = $ap['descr'];
    $price = $ap['rrp'];
?>
    <div class = "section_4">
        <h1 class = "food_h2"><?php echo $name; ?></h2>
        <br><img src = "img/products/hassellback_pot.jpg" class = "img_dis">
        <br><h1 class = "food_h2"><?php echo $description; ?></h1>
        <br><h1 class = "food_h2">£ <?php echo $price; ?></h1>
        <button class = "basket_btn" type = "button"> Buy </button>
    </div>
<?php
} // end the loop after using the values
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems, that your HTML- generation should be inside the loop, not outside:

```
<?php 
      $products = get_product_details(); 
      foreach($products as $ap) {
          $name = $ap['pro_name'];
          $description = $ap['descr'];
          $price = $ap['rrp'];  
          ?>
          <div class = "section_4">
                <h1 class = "food_h2"><?php echo $name; ?></h2>
                <br><img src = "img/products/hassellback_pot.jpg" class = "img_dis">
                <br><h1 class = "food_h2"><?php echo $description; ?></h1>
                <br><h1 class = "food_h2">£ <?php echo $price; ?></h1>
                <button class = "basket_btn" type = "button"> Buy </button>
          </div>
          <?php 
     } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<article class = "main_area2">
   <h1 class = "food_h1">Menu</h1>
   <br>
   <section class = "menu_section">
       <?php foreach(get_product_details() as $ap): ?>
       <div class = "section_4">
           <h1 class = "food_h2"><?php echo $ap['pro_name']; ?></h1>
           <br>
           <img src = "img/products/hassellback_pot.jpg" class = "img_dis">
           <br>
           <h1 class = "food_h2"><?php echo $ap['descr'] ?></h1>
           <br>
           <h1 class = "food_h2">£ <?php $ap['rrp']; ?></h1>
           <button class = "basket_btn" type = "button"> Buy </button>
       </div>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
   </section>
</article>
```

Comment: This answer looks like an accurate end result. It would be clearer if you describe why the asker's code isn't working and what this code does differently.